# i keep getting a 419 error page expired when i try to upload an image in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

this is my edit.blade.php where i show the form to update the user profile and upload thier image

```
<!-- form start -->
                  <form action="{{ route('profile.update') }}" method="POST" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  @csrf

                  <div class="card-body">
                        @if (session('status'))
                            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                {{ session('status') }}
                            </div>
                        @endif
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="profile_image" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Profile Image</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="profile_image" type="file" class="form-control" name="profile_image">
                                @if (auth()->user()->image)
                                    <code>{{ auth()->user()->profile()->image }}</code>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="address" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Enter First Name:') }}</label> ....
```

this is my Profilescontroller where i'm calling the updateprofile() from;

```
 public function updateProfile(Request $request)
    {
        // Form validation
        $request->validate([
            'profile_image'    => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2040',
            'address'          => 'required',
            'phoneno'          => 'required',
            'sex'              => 'required',
            'martial_status'   => 'required'
        ]);

        // Get current user
        $user = User::findOrFail(auth()->user()->id);
        // Set user name
        $user->accno = $request->input('accno');

        //check if a profile image has been uploaded
        if ($request->has('profile_image')) {
            // Get image file
            $image = $request->file('profile_image');
            // Make a image name based on user name and current timestamp
            $name = Str::slug($request->input('accno')).'_'.time();
            // Define folder path
            $folder = '/uploads/images/';
            // Make a file path where image will be stored [ folder path + file name + file extension]
            $filePath = $folder.$name. '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // Upload image
            $this->uploadOne($image, $folder, 'public' , $name);
            // Set user profile image path in database to filePath
            $user->profile()->profile_image = $filePath;
        }
        // Persist user record to database
        $user->save();

        // Return user back and show a flash message
        return redirect()->back()->with(['status' => 'Profile updated successfully.']);
    }
```

please i need help reviewing my code, i google my error and the only so,ution is to add ***crsf*** which i have done.

Comment: issue happen when submitting the form?

Comment: Are you using resource controller? Show your routes file.

Comment: i added the method('POST') to leave the page but i'm getting this new error ***BadMethodCallException
Method App\Http\Controllers\ProfilesController::uploadOne does not exist.***    even though i previously added ***use App\Traits\UploadTrait;*** in my profilescontroller

Comment: Its saying `uploadOne() ` does not exist, in `ProfilesController`.

Comment: yes but i called it in ```namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use illuminate\Http\Resquest;
use App\Traits\UploadTrait;
use App\Http\Requests; ```

Comment: Show your route file.

Comment: ```Route::get('/profile', 'ProfilesController@index');
Route::get('/profile/show', 'ProfilesController@show')->name('profiles.show');
Route::post('/profile/update', 'ProfilesController@updateProfile')->name('profile.update');```

Comment: Check your  `uploadOne()`method or update that method in question.

Comment: ```namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

trait UploadTrait
{
    public function uploadOne(UploadedFile $uploadedFile, $folder = null, $disk = 'public', $filename = null)
    {
        $name = !is_null($filename) ? $filename : Str::random(25);

        $file = $uploadedFile->storeAs($folder, $name.'.'.$uploadedFile->getClientOriginalExtension(), $disk);

        return $file;
    }
}```

Comment: the uploadOne() method is in Traits/UploadTraits.php but the code in the file doesn't highlight

Comment: In `ProfileController()` you first line must be `use UploadTraits`. Do you have this line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204401/discussion-between-toby-nwude-and-prashant-deshmukh).